# When inserting PHP inside a PHP file it then breaks the HTML also on the page

Tags: php, html, forms

I have an index.php file which is on the local server. By its self the code displays fine. But when I add the HTML the page "This page isn’t working" shows up.

Also if I keep the html code (inside the index.php file) and remove the PHP the page display correctly with the correct HTML and so I add the php it breaks again. I am following along to something and they put the PHP in its tags before the HTML.

Fairly new in comparison to people out there so maybe it is something very obvious ;)

Also all the HTML , head,body tags are in place at the start at end of html

I have an index.php file which is on the local server. By its self the code displays fine. But when I add the HTML the page "This page isn’t working" shows up.

Also if I keep the html code (inside the index.php file) and remove the PHP the page display correctly with the correct HTML and so I add the php it breaks again. I am following along to something and they  put the PHP in its tags before the HTML.

Fairly new in comparison to people out there so maybe it is something very obvious ;)

Place php elsewhere in the document

```
<?php
        // Failed messages
        $msg = '';
        $msgClass = ''; // So you can sort a Bootstrap warning 
        class to this // 

        // check for submit
        if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'submit')){
            echo "Submitted";

        // This is looking at the submit hmtl button and then 
        printing out submitted message //

            // Get form data
            $name = $_POST['name']
            $email = $_POST['email']
            $message = $_POST['message'];
            // collecting HTML form data into PHP variables //

        // Check required fields //
        // if not empty (!empty) field & 
        if(!empty($email) && !empty($email) && !empty($message)) {
            // if none are this are empty then we've passed //

        } else {
            //failed
            $msg = 'Please make sure all the fields are filled in';
        }; $msgClass = 'alert-danger';
    };      

?>
```

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Website 1</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/website1/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>
        <!-- Form -->
        <form action="contact-form.php" method="post">
        <p>First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" /></p>
        <p>Last name: <input type="text" name="firstname" /></p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

        <!-- Form END -->

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js 
  </script>
```

```
</body>
```

Comment: check your error log, it means your PHP got syntax error

Comment: You are missing quotes and closing tag here --> `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js`

Comment: // This is looking at the submit hmtl button and then 
        printing out submitted message //  is not a valid multiline comment.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js
```

should be

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js">
```

Also be careful about your multi-line comments in PHP, you either need // at the start of each line or to open and close them with /* and */. In particular, I'm referring to the lines:

```
        // This is looking at the submit hmtl button and then 
        printing out submitted message //
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `http 500` response (`internal server error`) because you got a syntax error in your `PHP` code.

`class to this` <--- this line throws an error, something like: `syntax error, unexpected 'this' (T_STRING)`

same with `printing out submitted message` <--- would be something like `syntax error, unexpected 'out' (T_STRING)`

Change those lines:

```
    $msgClass = ''; // So you can sort a Bootstrap warning 
    class to this //
```

to this:

```
    $msgClass = ''; /* So you can sort a Bootstrap warning 
    class to this */
```

And those lines:

```
// This is looking at the submit hmtl button and then 
        printing out submitted message //
```

to this:

```
/* This is looking at the submit hmtl button and then 
        printing out submitted message */
```